# Basic CSS not being applied to div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my own website, and it was going great until I tried to make it responsive (with @media). Now, my .top class is not applying to my div (look at `<div class="top"><h1>Awesurio Home Page</h1></div>` specifically).  I have supplied my full HTML and CSS that applies to the actual webpage.  The nav CSS was working before, so I have not posted it.  If you want it, I can.

```css
  h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: #222222;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16pt;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  [class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col-s-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-s-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-s-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-s-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-s-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-s-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-s-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-s-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-s-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-s-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-s-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-s-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .top {
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #222;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
  }
  .aside {
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
  .footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale="1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Awesurio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bodystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bun top"></div>
        <div class="filling"></div>
        <div class="bun bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="green">
        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="red">
        <a href="test1.html">test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="yellow">
        <a href="test2.html">test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="purple">
        <a href="test3.html">test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <div class="top">
    <h1>Awesurio Home Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-s-12">
      <p>Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff .Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.S tuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.Stuff.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Both of these worked before I added the @media, so maybe that is the culprit?  I'm really just starting out in HTML so I could have easily made a rookie mistake.

Comment: why not use bootstrap

Comment: Why WOULD you use Bootstrap in this case? An extra ton of page weight instead of just finding a fix to one issue just so you can look like every other website out there.

Comment: I wanted to try doing CSS on my own the first time around. :)

Comment: Aureus this is definitely the best way to achieve in anything. Sure you can gain valuable insight from looking at something like Bootstrap, but you aren't going to truly progress until you write it from scratch yourself. Also every other dev out there uses Bootstrap and for the most part their sites look exactly the same. Keep doing what you are doing no matter how hard it gets and you will be 100 times better than the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS, add in the missing closing bracket for your p declaration:

```
p {
    color: #222222;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16pt;
 } // <- This was missing
```

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/cs2hvmnz/1/